# Error implementing queue using linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm implementing a queue using linked lists in C. Here's my structure -

```
typedef struct llist node;
struct llist
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

I'm facing problem while executing `push()`. Here's my `push()` definition -

```
void push(node *head,int n)
{
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        head=(node *)(malloc((sizeof(node))));
        head->data=n;
        head->next=NULL;
        printf("=>%d\n",head->data);
    }
    else
    {
        node *ptr;
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=(node *)(malloc((sizeof(node))));
        ptr=ptr->next;
        ptr->data=n;
        ptr->next=NULL;
    }
    return;
}
```

and here's my `main()` function -

```
int main()
{
    int choice,n;
    node *head;
    head=NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter your choice -\n1. Push\n2. Pop\n3. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter element to push: ");
                scanf("%d",&n);
                push(head,n);
                if (head==NULL)//To check if head is NULL after returning from push()
                {
                    printf("Caught here!\n");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                pop(head);
                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that after `push()` exits in `case 1`, `head` becomes `NULL` again, ie, the *Caught here!* statement does get executed. How is it possible?

Comment: You are modifying a local copy of the list in `push()`.  To modify the one in `main()` you need a double-pointer.  `push()` should be `void push(node **head, int n)` and wherever you use `head` in `push()` you should be using `*head` instead, and you should pass `push(&head, n)` when you call it.

Comment: `head` in `main` function and `head` in `pop` function are two different variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are calling by value and you are modifying the value (in this case node *head), the value is not retained in `main()`. So either

1. Pass pointer to node *head

   `push(&head,n);` in `main()`

   and modify

   `void push(node **head,int n)`
2. Return head

   `node* push(node *head,int n)`

   and in `main()`:

   `head=push(head,n);`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the accepted answer, another option would be to declare head variable as global. Then you don't need to pass head as a parameter to push or pop.

Comment: Yes, I did keep it as a backup option. But I wanted to know why the above code wasn't working. Any ways good suggestion.